# Given an Integer n, and "n=x+(x+1)+(x+2)+(x+3)" where "x" is a Integer, how discover "x"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

If "n=10", so "x=1": "1+2+3+4=10".
how discover "x" if "n=5"? Or "n=29"? Or "n=-7"?
I guess that, in some cases, there not exists a Integer Number for "x"; how discover this cases?

Comment: I would write $x+(x+1)+(x+2)+(x+3)$ as $4x+6$. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$4x+6=n$ and $x=\frac{n-6}{4}$.

Comment: And so there is no integer solution for $x$ if $n-6$ is not divisible by $4$, ie $n$ must be two more than a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x=0$, $n $ must be $6$.

for $x=1$, we need $n=1+2+3+4=10$

each time we add $4$.

so we must have $n=6+4k $.